# Java cast Arraylist to JsonElement

Tags: java, ajax, json, gson

I would like use this method:

> ```
> json.add("myText", getList(id));
> ```

The function getList(id) return an arraylist, but the method json.add would like a JsonElement.

So, how can i cast an arraylist in JsonElement ?

I test this, but it doesn't work:

> ```
> json.add("myText", (JsonElement)getList(id));
> ```

I test this too:

> JsonElement jelement = new JsonElement() {
>
> ```
>  private ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
>
>  public ArrayList<String> getList(){ 
>      return this.list;
>  }
> ```
>
> };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

com.google.gson has methods for serializing an ArrayList (or any collection).  Once you have serialized it, you can parse the string with a JSONParser:

```
JSONParser.parse(gson.toJson(getList(id)));
```

ref: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples

Comment: new JSONParser.parse(new gson().toJson(getList(id)));

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a `JsonElement` out of a `List`, you can use `JsonTree`:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
jsonObject.add("myList", gson.toJsonTree(myList));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant cast it and I cant see a way to convert it with the API methods. I think you will need to create your own method to convert list to array.

e.g.

```
private JsonElement convertToJsonElement(List<Object> list)
```

Then call it like this:

```
json.add("myText", convertToJsonElement(getList(id)));
```

Alternatively, if you have acces to the `getList` method, you could change this to return a JsonElement

Comment: and how can I convert to JsonElement in my function ? What should I do in my method ?

Comment: Create a new JsonElement -> Copy the data from the list to the JsonElement (probably via set methods on the JsonElement) -> return the new json element

Comment: I am trying this, but I doesn't work:
>JsonElement jelement = new JsonElement() {
>            private ArrayList<String> list112 = new >ArrayList<String>();
>            
>            public ArrayList<String> getList(){
>                return this.list112;
>            }
>        };

Comment: I cant understand that code, maybe add it to your question in a formatted code block

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to take a step back and understand what you're trying to do.

I assume you want to create a mapping between "myText" and an array of other objects.

In order to do this, you simply need to call Gson.toJson(map) where map holds key myText and value as List or array.  In other words:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> mapJson = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Object>>();
mapJson.put("myText", getList(id));

String outputJson = Gson.toJson(mapJson);
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, I implore you to explain your objective so that we may help you do it in the way that Gson supports rather than the way you want to do it.